# which javascript chart library should use for interactive chart

Tags: javascript, charts

I know this question has been asked extensively,so now I confused between options. I want to create application which use populate charts on browser. chart should be interactive and it's conventional chart (pie,bar etc). I liked to go to for D3 but it seems I may fall short on time basis to learn that. so I checked on other libraries like google chart,DC,morris,C3,nvd3,ember chart where DC,C3,nvd3 are create on top of D3. google chart may be restricted due to security reasons. so which library should I prefer? should I go for google one if no security measures are there or any alternative are there?please help me out because as I am digging more,more I am getting confused and I am running out of time to create PoCs for this libraries

Comment: Google charts can't be use offline nor work in offline. I have used NVD3. It is very responsive and efficient. But it is not the only one.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest [AmChart](https://www.amcharts.com). I has lot of examples and good documentation. Additionally you can create interactive maps. And you can create chart easily using a chat creating [tool](https://live.amcharts.com/new/). Which is totally cool.

Comment: hi thanks for quick response? is it license because I can see buy a license option there

Comment: It's free and powerful. You can buy for enterprise.

Answer (score 1):

There are really a lot of chart library it's really hard to pick one. And as a beginner i wanted to just make a working chart app not to go deeper so i picked highcharts, it was very easy to understand for me i hope it works for you too.

https://www.highcharts.com/

this is my demo project if it helps, i wanted a dynamic chart too:

https://github.com/Resoguy/atterbergLimitsApp,

http://madrhino.gq/atterbergLimitsApp/

Comment: hi thanks for the answer but high chart for commercial use it is paid. I need to some open sources

Answer (score 1):

Try to explore this list: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_frameworks

If your project is non-profit, I'd suggest [AnyChart](http://www.anychart.com) because then you'll be able to use it for free. It has a lot of chart types, ways to work with data, customization options, and ready-to-use samples, as well as comprehensive documentation and API reference.

Answer (score 0):

For one of my project I use [chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/). I think is good is easy and is have also good documentation